# How to cross compile go application for FreeBSD within a Raspberry pi 1 model B

Tags: go, cross-compiling, freebsd, coredump

On a [Raspberry Pi 1 model B](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/model-b/) I installed [FreeBSD 10.3](https://www.freebsd.org/where.html) using the SD Card Images [RPI-B](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/arm/armv6/ISO-IMAGES/10.3/FreeBSD-10.3-RELEASE-arm-armv6-RPI-B.img.xz).

I can boot, get network, ssh into it, etc, all seems to be ok and functional. This is part of the dmesg output:

```
FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE #0 r297264: Fri Mar 25 08:01:14 UTC 2016
    root@releng1.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/arm.armv6/usr/src/sys/RPI-B arm
FreeBSD clang version 3.4.1 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot1-final 208032) 20140512
VT: init without driver.
CPU: ARM1176JZ-S rev 7 (ARM11J core)
 Supported features: ARM_ISA THUMB2 JAZELLE ARMv4 Security_Ext
 WB enabled LABT branch prediction enabled
  16KB/32B 4-way instruction cache
  16KB/32B 4-way write-back-locking-C data cache
real memory  = 503312384 (479 MB)
avail memory = 483127296 (460 MB)
```

On a mac os X (10.11.6) with go 1.7.1:

```
go version go1.7.1 darwin/amd64
```

I am cross compile this code:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        t := time.Now().UTC()
        fmt.Println("Location:", t.Location(), ":Time:", t.Format(time.RFC3339Nano))
}
```

With:

```
env GOOS=freebsd GOARCH=arm go build
```

Running the generated binary on the raspberry-pi generates a coredump:

```
freebsd@rpi-b:~ % ./time 
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

On the `time.core` after typing:

```
$ strings time.core
```

besides many characters I see this:

```
fatal error: cgo callback before cgo call
```

Any idea how what flags to use or how to properly cross-compile for FreeBSD within a Raspberry pi ?

Comment: How if you add `GOARM=6` or even lower arm version (v5) when cross compiling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @putu comment, I was available to cross-compile using `GOARM=6`

```
env GOOS=freebsd GOARCH=arm GOARM=6 go build
```