# Compiling go for FreeBSD 13.2 arm

Tags: go, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, freebsd

I would like to compile some Go code for a FreeBSD machine:

```
quark$ uname -a
FreeBSD quark 13.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 13.2-RELEASE releng/13.2-n254617-525ecfdad597 RPI-B arm
```

I am cross compiling from a Linux machine:

```
archlinux$ uname -a
Linux archlinux 6.7.6-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri, 23 Feb 2024 16:31:48 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
archlinux$ go version
go version go1.22.0 linux/amd64
```

Some Go code:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        t := time.Now().UTC()
        fmt.Println("Now:", t.Format(time.RFC3339Nano), "!")
}
```

Compile steps:

```
archlinux$ export GOARCH=arm
archlinux$ export GOOS=freebsd
archlinux$ export GOARM=6
archlinux$ go build time.go
archlinux$ file time
time: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (FreeBSD), statically linked, for FreeBSD 12.3, FreeBSD-style, Go BuildID=xdfWXxT__aMomffvV1zx/MU0rcYoRAe-TcUCtTzOB/NTCZChXbctQS2ubirhCR/-Ez3jurVLV9a1Wskk5xa, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Yet when I attempt to execute this binary on the target machine:

```
quark$ file time
time: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (FreeBSD), statically linked, for FreeBSD 12.3, FreeBSD-style, Go BuildID=xdfWXxT__aMomffvV1zx/MU0rcYoRAe-TcUCtTzOB/NTCZChXbctQS2ubirhCR/-Ez3jurVLV9a1Wskk5xa, with debug_info, not stripped
quark$ ./time
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Related thread: [How to cross compile go application for FreeBSD within a Raspberry pi 1 model B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678131/how-to-cross-compile-go-application-for-freebsd-within-a-raspberry-pi-1-model-b), did not solve my issue